# open(2) a file from existing descriptor

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, fcntl

## Background

I have multiple threads in the same process that are all installing [`fcntl(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) locks on a given file. These locks must block, thus to achieve intra-process blocking I must use Open file description locks (or OFD locks, see `fcntl(2)`). And it is documented that:

> Open file description locks placed via the same open file
> description (i.e., via the same file descriptor, or via a
> duplicate of the file descriptor created by fork(2), dup(2),
> fcntl() F_DUPFD, and so on) are always compatible: if a new lock
> is placed on an already locked region, then the existing lock is
> converted to the new lock type.  (Such conversions may result in
> splitting, shrinking, or coalescing with an existing lock as
> discussed above.)
>
> On the other hand, open file description locks may conflict with
> each other when they are acquired via different open file
> descriptions.  Thus, the **threads in a multithreaded program can
> use open file description locks to synchronize access to a file
> region by having each thread perform its own open(2)** on the file
> and applying locks via the resulting file descriptor.

Thus, when a thread is booting up, it must open its own descriptor via `open`. It should be noted that the "main thread" has the file already open and threads come and go throughout the processes lifetime.

## Question

So I was thinking, is there any way I can re-use an existing file descriptor to open a separate descriptor to the same file without `dup(2)`?

In otherwords, if I had file descriptor *A*, but do not know the filename, can I open descriptor *B* pointing to that same file *A* is?

Comment: I'd recommend keeping track of the file name associated with each file descriptor so that you don't have to futz around with `/proc`.  Why wouldn't the threads be able to know which file was associated with a given file descriptor?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah I could do that... but my question is on the basis of my curiosity rather than my pragmatism. Out of all of the syscalls available in POSIX alone I'm surprised this isn't blatantly possible: there must be a reason why there's no straightforward answer.

Comment: It's very seldom a requirement so no one has produced such a system call.   Programs know which files they have open and usually use the file name.  There are a few times when it might be helpful.  For example, if you have a file descriptor for a removed file (no actual filename; usually, it's a temporary file), then there is no name to use to reopen the file.  I think your `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` mechanism would work even for that.  There's always a risk with file names that the original file has been removed and a new one put in its place.  That's why there are functions like `fchmod()`.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is as follows, whereas `fd` is the original file descriptor and `fd2` is the "deep cloned" descriptor.

```
char buff[500]
sprintf(buff, "/proc/%d/fd/%d", getpid(), fd);
fd2 = open(buff, O_RDWR)
```

However, it feels dirty. I was hoping there is a system call to do this.